# form input search route

Tags: html, webforms

Имеется форма

```
<form method="post" name="do" action="" class="search-area">
    <input type="submit" value="Поиск">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Введите текст для поиска...">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</form>
```

Как после ввода и нажатия отправлять юзера по адресу
[http://localhost/index.php/main/search?search=слово](http://localhost/index.php/main/search?search=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE)
Где слово это переменная $search

Comment: где переменная `$search` ?

Comment: и если у вас вопрос про php, то приведите проблемный кусок кода на php

Comment: @Дима, если вам дан правильный ответ, то отметьте его как решение вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Если имеется ввиду как при отправке формы получить запрос на страницу `http://localhost/index.php/main/search?search=слово`, то ваш html c правками будет такой

```
<form method="get" name="do" action="/index.php/main/search" class="search-area">
    <input type="submit" value="Поиск">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Введите текст для поиска...">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: :) Вот ТС намудрил вопрос.

Comment: Благодарю это то что нужно

Comment: @Дима тогда слева должна быть кнопка для принятия ответа